# WS Import issue in Netbeans while creating Web Service Client Stub

Tags: web-services, netbeans, wsimport, netbeans-11

WS Import issue in netbeans when try to create webservice client in maven project using wsdl.

```
--- jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport (wsimport-generate-v34.0) @ masterdata-workday ---
Processing: file:/C:/Users/ei10441/OneDrive%20-%20DEVRY/Documents/NetBeansProjects/masterdata-workday/src/wsdl/wdd9-impl-services15.workday.com/xxx/service/chuto1/Human_Resources/v34.0.wsdl
jaxws:wsimport args: [-keep, -s, C:\Users\ei10441\OneDrive - DEVRY\Documents\NetBeansProjects\masterdata-workday\target\generated-sources\jaxws-wsimport, -d, C:\Users\ei10441\OneDrive - DEVRY\Documents\NetBeansProjects\masterdata-workday\target\classes, -verbose, -encoding, UTF-8, -extension, -Xnocompile, -p, com.devry.masterdata.workday, -catalog, C:\Users\ei10441\OneDrive - DEVRY\Documents\NetBeansProjects\masterdata-workday\src\jax-ws-catalog.xml, -wsdllocation, https://wdd9-impl-services15.workday.com/xxx/service/chuto1/Human_Resources/v34.0?wsdl, "file:/C:/Users/ei10441/OneDrive%20-%20DEVRY/Documents/NetBeansProjects/masterdata-workday/src/wsdl/wdd9-impl-services15.workday.com/xxx/service/chuto1/Human_Resources/v34.0.wsdl"]
unrecognized parameter -


Usage: wsimport [options] <WSDL_URI>

where [options] include:
  -b <path>                 specify jaxws/jaxb binding files or additional schemas
                            (Each <path> must have its own -b)
  -B<jaxbOption>            Pass this option to JAXB schema compiler
  -catalog <file>           specify catalog file to resolve external entity references
                            supports TR9401, XCatalog, and OASIS XML Catalog format.
  -d <directory>            specify where to place generated output files
  -encoding <encoding>      specify character encoding used by source files
  -extension                allow vendor extensions - functionality not specified
                            by the specification.  Use of extensions may
                            result in applications that are not portable or
                            may not interoperate with other implementations
  -help                     display help
  -httpproxy:<proxy>        set a HTTP proxy. Format is [user[:password]@]proxyHost:proxyPort
                            (port defaults to 8080)
  -keep                     keep generated files
  -p <pkg>                  specifies the target package
  -quiet                    suppress wsimport output
  -s <directory>            specify where to place generated source files
  -target <version>         generate code as per the given JAXWS spec version
                            Defaults to 2.2, Accepted values are 2.0, 2.1 and 2.2
                            e.g. 2.0 will generate compliant code for JAXWS 2.0 spec
  -verbose                  output messages about what the compiler is doing
  -version                  print version information
  -fullversion              print full version information
  -wsdllocation <location>  @WebServiceClient.wsdlLocation value
  -clientjar <jarfile>      Creates the jar file of the generated artifacts along with the
                            WSDL metadata required for invoking the web service.
  -generateJWS              generate stubbed JWS implementation file
  -implDestDir <directory>  specify where to generate JWS implementation file
  -implServiceName <name>   local portion of service name for generated JWS implementation
  -implPortName <name>      local portion of port name for generated JWS implementation

Extensions:
  -XadditionalHeaders              map headers not bound to request or response message to 
                                   Java method parameters
  -Xauthfile                       file to carry authorization information in the format 
                                   http://username:password@example.org/stock?wsdl
  -Xdebug                          print debug information
  -Xno-addressing-databinding      enable binding of W3C EndpointReferenceType to Java
  -Xnocompile                      do not compile generated Java files
  -XdisableAuthenticator           disable Authenticator used by JAX-WS RI,
                                   -Xauthfile option will be ignored if set
  -XdisableSSLHostnameVerification disable the SSL Hostname verification while fetching
                                   wsdls

Examples:
  wsimport stock.wsdl -b stock.xml -b stock.xjb
  wsimport -d generated http://example.org/stock?wsdl

------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 27.405 s
Finished at: 2020-04-22T14:44:08+05:30
Final Memory: 14M/309M
Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport (wsimport-generate-v34.0) on project masterdata-workday: Mojo failed - check output -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Any idea what is issue and how to fix it in netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

Changed the folder structure to one without hyphen and space and this got fixed for me.

It appears may be "OneDrive - DEVRY" is getting stucked